# How to add two columns value and perform where condition in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

This is my table:

```
id       remaining_amount     additional_amount
1             200                   0
2             100                -100
3             300                 100
4             200                 -50
```

I'm trying to get the rows which have a sum of *remaining_amount* + *additional_amount* > 0 .

```
$result = $this->model->where('remaining_amount' + 'total' > 0)->get();
```

it didn't work. Then I tried like this:

```
$result = DB::table('cash')->select(DB::raw('remaining_amount+additional_amount AS total'))
                ->where('total','>',0)
                ->get();
```

It doesn't work either.

Please show me the way to solve this.

Comment: You can not perform where condition on calculated value

Comment: why not you use aggregate method to sum

Answer (score 3):

Try this using `whereRaw`:

```
$query = DB::table('cash')
    ->whereRaw("(remaining_amount+additional_amount AS total) > 0)")
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not perform where condition on calculated value. Try using [filter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-filter) from [laravel collection](http://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections) to get the desired output.

```
$result = DB::table('cash')
    ->select(DB::raw('(remaining_amount+additional_amount) AS total'))
    ->get();
```

Performing filter

```
return collect($result)->filter(function($value){
    return $value->total > 0;
})->values()->all();
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you sohuld use aggregate method to sum as

```
$result = DB::table('cash')->SELECT SUM(remaining_amount)+additional_amount AS total')->where('total','>',0)->get();
```

Hope it will work for you

Answer (score -1):

```
$result = DB::table('cash')->get();

$result = collect($result)->filter(function($value){
    return $value->remaining_amount + $value->additional_amount > 0;
    })->values()->all();
```

Got it. Thanks