# How to use query builder to get data depending on the sum of two column in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

For example, I have a table,

```
id   apple   orange
 1       1        1
 2       1        2
 3       2        2
```

and I want to get the item where $apple + $orange > $threshold. For example, if $threshold = 3, then the answer will be No.3. How can I do this in the Laravel query builder?

I tried the filter() from this question: [How to add two columns value and perform where condition in laravel eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42128732/how-to-add-two-columns-value-and-perform-where-condition-in-laravel-eloquent)

```
$set = collect($set)->filter(function ($val) use ($threshold) {
    return $val->apple + $val->orange > $threshold;
})->values()->all();
```

It does work but looks really ugly to me... Are there any other ways to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I interpret your requirement as being equivalent to the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM fruits
WHERE apple + orange > $threshold
```

If so, then you can try using `whereRaw` with this condition:

```
DB::table('fruits')
    ->whereRaw("apple + orange > ?", array($threshold));
    ->get();
```

Comment: @sumit I'm actually quite lousy at Laravel questions, because I have never used it in real life.  I sort of went the query route first, then slowly worked out the Laravel code.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I'm sorry I didn't make it right. Actually, my question is also including using a variable in the query builder. Please have a look at the edited question. Thanks!

Comment: Just found it on the spec, haha. Thanks, mate. You're awesome!